# How can I implement a function differently depending on if a generic type implements a trait or not?

Tags: rust, generic-programming

I'd like to make the implementation of `do_something` conditional based on if the generic type `T` implements `Debug` or not. Is there any way to do something like this?

```
struct A(i32);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B(i32);

struct Foo<T> {
    data: T,
    /* more fields */
}

impl<T> Foo<T> {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        /* ... */
        println!("Success!");
    }

    fn do_something(&self)
    where
        T: Debug,
    {
        /* ... */
        println!("Success on {:?}", self.data);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        data: A(3), /* ... */
    };
    foo.do_something(); // should call first implementation, because A
                        // doesn't implement Debug

    let foo = Foo {
        data: B(2), /* ... */
    };
    foo.do_something(); // should call second implementation, because B
                        // does implement Debug
}
```

I think one way to do this is to create a trait where we have to define `do_something(&Self)`, but I'm not sure. My code snippet is what I will try first.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=171215eec4602191d595ac5cfe1f9b00&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015 ?

Comment: @Stargateur what I mean is to do **A** if _T_ implements a Trait, and do **B** if _T_ doesn't implement a Trait, all of this under one common name like `do_something(&Self)`

Comment: It's not possible both must implement the trait in this context. :/ Maybe you should read about trait and how to use them.

Comment: Yeah, I supposed it, but just wondering if I didn't know something ultra advanced, but it will be cool to see something like `if T impl Debug { A } else { B }` inside functions, I think it's possible because its like conditional compilation, all of this can be checked at compile time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution based on the nightly feature [*specialization*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844):

```
#![feature(specialization)]

use std::fmt::Debug;

struct A(i32);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct B(i32);

struct Foo<T> {
    data: T,
    /* more fields */
}

trait Do {
    fn do_something(&self);
}

impl<T> Do for Foo<T> {
    default fn do_something(&self) {
        /* ... */
        println!("Success!");
    }
}

impl<T> Do for Foo<T>
where
    T: Debug,
{
    fn do_something(&self) {
        /* ... */
        println!("Success on {:?}", self.data);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        data: A(3), /* ... */
    };
    foo.do_something(); // should call first implementation, because A
                        // doesn't implement Debug

    let foo = Foo {
        data: B(2), /* ... */
    };
    foo.do_something(); // should call second implementation, because B
                        // does implement Debug
}
```

The first step is to create a trait which defines `do_something(&self)`. Now, we define two `impl`s of this trait for `Foo<T>`: a generic "parent" `impl` which is implemented for all `T` and a specialized "child" `impl` which is only implemented for the subset where `T` implements `Debug`. The child `impl` may specialize items from the parent `impl`. These items we want to specialize need to be marked with the `default` keyword in the parent `impl`. In your example, we want to specialize `do_something`.

Comment: I had something like this in mind but I didn't know about specialization feature.