# function "optional trait bound" in rust

Tags: rust

I want to have something like optional trait bound for function. Where if `T` implements that type - do something.

```rust
fn test<T: Eq + ?Debug>(a:T, b:T){
    if a!=b{
        println!("Not equal!");
        if (T impl Debug){
            println!("{:?} != {:?}", a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe [`impls` crate](https://github.com/nvzqz/impls#examples)

Comment: That requires [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html), not yet available.

Comment: @user4815162342 I thought about specialization, how does it help? Function signature still have to be `<T:Eq + ?Debug>` - either way, I can't pass value to specialized trait implementation

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov how function signature will look like with that crate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I implement a function differently depending on if a generic type implements a trait or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141200/how-can-i-implement-a-function-differently-depending-on-if-a-generic-type-implem)

Comment: @tower120 I think specialization would help, but would require some legwork. Basically you'd crate a trait `Test` with one blanket implementation for `Eq` and another for `Eq + Debug` (this is what specialization makes possible). `test` would then require `Test` and would call its method that is no-op when `Debug` is unavailable and prints the contents otherwise.

Comment: Is it possible to do with `min_specialization`? Since I read that `specialization` feature "unsound".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @user4815162342 commented, using specialization, this is possible.

I'll provide a slightly different approach from what they specified in their comment, to keep the same `if ... { ... }` setup that you had in your original code.

The idea is to have a trait `AsMaybeDebug` with an associated type `Debug`, which always implements `Debug` and a function to go from `&Self` to `Option<&Self::Debug>`:

```rust
trait AsMaybeDebug {
    type Debug: Debug;
    fn as_maybe_debug(&self) -> Option<&Self::Debug>;
}
```

After this we make a default impl for all `T`, with the debug type being `!`, the never type, and always return `None`.

```rust
impl<T> AsMaybeDebug for T {
    default type Debug = !;
    default fn as_maybe_debug(&self) -> Option<&Self::Debug> {
        None
    }
}
```

Instead of the never type, you could choose any type that always implemented `Debug` but still returning `None`.

Afterwards we specialize for `T: Debug` by returning `Self`:

```
impl<T: Debug> AsMaybeDebug for T {
    type Debug = Self;
    fn as_maybe_debug(&self) -> Option<&Self::Debug> {
        Some(self)
    }
}
```

Finally in `test` we just call `as_maybe_debug` and check if `T: Debug`

```rust
fn test<T: Eq>(a: T, b: T){
    if a != b {
        println!("Not equal!");
        
        if let (Some(a), Some(b)) = (a.as_maybe_debug(), b.as_maybe_debug()) {
            println!("{:?} != {:?}", a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

You can check in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=1582c1347d03afd28396ddb7c4609b34) both that it works and that the assembly generated for `test_non_debug` doesn't have any debugging calls, only the single call to `std::io::_print`.

It unfortunately isn't possible to retrieve the original `a` or `b` inside the `if` after calling `as_maybe_debug`.

This is due to `<Self as AsMaybeDebug>::Debug` not being
convertible back to `Self`.
This can be fixed, but not easily as it requires updates from the standard library.

Requiring `AsMaybeDebug::Debug: AsRef<Self>` doesn't work for 2 reasons:

- 1. There is no `impl<T> AsRef<T> for T` yet, this is due to specialization still being incomplete, I assume.
- 2. There is no `impl<T> AsRef<T> for !` yet. Not sure if this impl can be made even with specialization or not, but it would be required.

Also, although the `specialization` can be unsound, I believe that the trait and it's impls cannot be used for unsoundness, you would need a specific setup to be able to generate unsoundness from it, which this lacks.

Answer (score -3):

As mentioned in the comments, you're looking for the [`impls` crate](https://github.com/nvzqz/impls), which does exactly what you want.

```
if impls!(T: Debug) {
  ...
}
```

Just for the sake of completeness, here's how you do it without an external crate dependency. I'm paraphrasing from [the way the `impls` developer explains the trick](https://github.com/nvzqz/impls/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L328).

Let's say we want to check whether some type implements `Debug`. First, let's define the "base case".

```
trait NotDebug {
  const IMPLS: bool = false;
}
```

We'll also provide a blanket implementation so that all types (which don't have a better answer) have a `IMPLS` constant equal to false.

```
impl<T> NotDebug for T {}
```

Now, let's make a simple type with a single generic type parameter.

```
struct IsDebug<T>(std::marker::PhantomData<T>);
```

[`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) is conceptually nonexistent and exists only to anchor the generic type `T` to our `IsDebug`. We can think of `IsDebug` as being effectively a singleton struct.

Now, we would like `IsDebug::<T>::IMPLS` to be true if (and only if) `T` implements `Debug`. Currently, `IsDebug::<T>::IMPLS` is always false, by a blanket implementation of `NotDebug`. But we can specify an inherent `impl` that applies conditionally.

```
impl<T: Debug> IsDebug<T> {
  const IMPLS: bool = true;
}
```

Since this is an `impl` on `IsDebug` itself, not on a trait implementation, it takes precedent over the `NotDebug` blanket implementation. In any case where `T: Debug`, the inherent `impl` kicks in and we get `true`. In any other case, the inherent `impl` fails, so we get the fallback blanket implementation which gives `false`.

[Try it in the Rust Playground!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e8f21fa4b06f079c463f471ea18155b)

Comment: But how I accept parameters with optional trait bounds in the first place? How this signature will look `fn test<T: Eq + ?Debug>(a:T, b:T)`?

Comment: This would only work when `T` is known to implement the trait inside the function (i.e. it's a specific type or a generic type with the trait in its bounds). So in when using a generic function, as in the question, it would always consider `T` to not implement `Debug` even if the actual type did. ([Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d82915b659a4ad4747fbfed887a5ab02))