# Create a Rust function that returns an Option<T> default for any type T?

Tags: rust

I have a problem where I need to create a function that takes an arbitrary type, but it needs to work differently for types that are Default vs types that are not.

I can't specialize a trait on the negative impl of Default because that feature isn't stable yet, but what I'd like is something like this:

```rust
fn my_func<T>() {
  if let Some(default) = get_default::<T>() {
    // Has default
  } else {
    // Has no default
  }
}
```

Is this possible with the stable version of Rust?

In this case, the `impls` crate doesn't work (https://crates.io/crates/impls) because it will believe that T (the generic parameter) is not `Default`.

Comment: again I have a better question, why do you want that ? no you can't without specialization

Comment: It's not quite the same, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68701910/6655004) should be close to what you want

Comment: If there was a way to do that, we wouldn't need `feature(specialization)`. No, there is no way.